# Задача о купюрах

Tags: алгоритм, delphi, pascal

В общем есть задача, кажется довольно легкой, но с ней у меня возникли проблемы. Прошу у Вас помощи.

> Вы сидите на первом сидении в
> маршрутном такси. Проезд в маршрутке
> стоит 10 рублей. Вам передают купюры
> достоинством в 10, 50 и 100 рублей (с
> каждой купюры – на билет за одного
> пассажира). Часть из них вы можете
> сразу раздать в качестве сдачи (её
> можно выдать полностью или частично).
> Остальные купюры вы передаете
> водителю. Какое наименьшее количество
> купюр вам придется передать водителю?
>
> Формат входных данных
>
> Вводится три целых неотрицательных
> числа (каждое не превосходит 100) –
> количество 10-, 50- и 100-рублевых
> купюр, которые вам передали.
>
> Формат выходных данных
>
> Выведите одно число – наименьшее
> возможное количество купюр, которое
> придется передать водителю.

На ум пришел жадный алгоритм, вот как я решаю:

```
program pr;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Math;

var
  a,b,c,ans,sum:int64;
  i:longint;

begin
  assignFile(input,'input.txt');
  assignFile(output,'output.txt');
  reset(input);
  rewrite(output);

  read(a,b,c);

  ans := 0;

  sum:=(a+b+c) * 10;

  for i:= 1 to c do
    if(sum > 0) then
    begin
      ans := ans + 1;
      sum := sum - 100;
    end
    else
    break;

  for i:= 1 to b do
    if(sum > 0) then
    begin
      ans := ans + 1;
      sum := sum - 50;
    end
    else
    break;

  if(sum > 0) then
    ans := ans + sum div 10;

  writeln(ans);

  closeFile(input);
  closeFile(output);
end.
```

Но дело в том, что это неправильно. Не проходит все тесты. Думаю есть жучок, а точнее какое-либо исключение из правила. Помогите, пожалуйста, его найти.

P.S. Вот, где можно проверить http://informatics.mccme.ru/moodle/mod/statements/view3.php?chapterid=776#1 (НЕ реклама)

Comment: Сдачу не надо высчитывать, необходимо узнать наименьшее возможное количество купюр, которое придется передать водителю, а как давать сдачу не моя проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение на  JS. К сожалению Delphi не знаю, но думаю алгоритм и так ясен.

```js
function calc( k10, k50, k100 ){
  //Всего купюр
  p = k10+k50+k100;

  //Cколько 50 можно не передавать
  if ( ( k100 - k50 ) >= 0 ){
    p = p - k50;
    k100 = k100 - k50;  //некоторые 100 превращаются в 50
    k50 = k50 + k50;    //С некоторых 100 нужно дать ещё по 40
  }
  else {
    p = p - k100;
    k50 = k50 + k100;   //Со всех 100 нужно дать ещё по 40
    k100 = 0;           //все 100 превращаются в 50
  }

  //Сколько 10 можно не передавать
  s10 = k100*9+k50*4;
  if ( ( k10 - s10 ) >= 0 ){
    p -= s10;           //некоторые 10 ушли на сдачу
  }
  else {
    p -= k10;           //все 10 ушли на сдачу
  }

  return [p];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Переписал на делфи, сдал. Решение частичное, прошло 4 теста, вместо моих 2 :) К сожалению это не полное решение.

Comment: Код в студию)

Answer (score 1):

Вот переписанный код на делфи, в комментарий не помещается.

```
program pr;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Math;

var
  p,k10,k50,k100,s10:integer;

begin
  assignFile(input,'input.txt');
  assignFile(output,'output.txt');
  reset(input);
  rewrite(output);

  read(k10,k50,k100);

  p := k10+k50+k100;

  if ( ( k100 - k50 ) >= 0 )then
  begin
    p := p - k50;
    k100 := k100 - k50;  
  end
  else
  begin
    p := p - k100;
    k100 := 0;         
  end;

  s10 := k100*9+k50*4;
  if ( ( k10 - s10 ) >= 0 ) then
  begin
    p := p - s10;          
  end
  else
  begin
    p := p - k10;           
  end;

  writeln(p);

  closeFile(input);
  closeFile(output);
end.
```

Comment: Исправил код (выше), теперь должно быть верно

    //Cколько 50 можно не передавать

    if ( ( k100 - k50 ) >= 0 ){
      p = p - k50;
      k50 = k50 + k50;      //С некоторых 100 нужно дать ещё по 40
      k100 = k100 - k50;  //некоторые 100 превращаются в 50
    }
    else {
      p = p - k100;
      k50 = k50 + k100; //Со всех 100 нужно дать ещё по 40
      k100 = 0;           //все 100 превращаются в 50
    }

Comment: Теперь даже на 1 1 1 не работает, пишет 3 вместо 1.

Comment: Сэкономил на временных переменных. Вот верный

     if ( ( k100 - k50 ) >= 0 ){ 
        p = p - k50;
        k100 = k100 - k50;  //некоторые 100 превращаются в 50 
        k50 = k50 + k50;    //С некоторых 100 нужно дать ещё по 40
      }
      else {
        p = p - k100;
        k50 = k50 + k100;   //Со всех 100 нужно дать ещё по 40
        k100 = 0;           //все 100 превращаются в 50
      }

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все работает! Буду разбираться в коде :)