# Код проходит не все тесты

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, условия

> Вы сидите на первом сидении в маршрутном такси. Проезд в маршрутке стоит 10 рублей. Вам передают купюры достоинством в 10, 50 и 100 рублей (с каждой купюры – на билет за одного пассажира). Часть из них вы можете сразу раздать в качестве сдачи (её можно выдать полностью или частично). Остальные купюры вы передаете водителю. Какое наименьшее количество купюр вам придется передать водителю?
>
> Входные данные
>   Вводится три целых неотрицательных числа (каждое не превосходит 100) – количество 10-, 50- и 100-рублевых купюр, которые вам передали.
>
> Выходные данные
>   Выведите одно число – наименьшее возможное количество купюр, которое придется передать водителю.

```
    n, m, k = map(int,input().split())
a = n + m + k
b = n * 10
c = m * 50
d = k * 100

if k * 100 >= n * 10 and k != 0 and n != 0:
    a -= n
    d -= b
elif k != 0 and n != 0:
    a -= (k * 10)
    d -= d
    if m * 50 >= n * 10:
        a -= n
    elif m != 0:
        a -= (m * 5)

if d != 0 and m != 0 and c >= d:
    a -= m
elif d != 0 and m != 0:
    a -= m
print(a)
```

код не проходит 2 теста из 10, что не так?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/45848/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%be-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%8e%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%85?rq=1

Comment: Извините но не могли бы вы сказать какой тест № 5 на informatics у этой задачи

Comment: у меня просто не проходит тест этот

Comment: Что такое "выдать сдачу частично" в данной задаче и к чему это?

Answer (score 3):

Сначала сдаём с сотен полтинниками, насколько возможно (все или часть сотен становится временными полтинниками)

После этого с оставшихся крупных сдаём червонцами.

```
n100 = 3
n50 = 4
n10 = 10
coins = n100 + n50 + n10
coins -= min(n100, n50)
n100 -= min(n100, n50)
coins -= min(n10, n100 * 9 + n50 * 4)
print(coins)
```

---

```
d10 = min(n100 * 9, n10)
n10 = n10 - d10
rest100 = n100 * 9 - d10
d10 = min(n50 * 4, n10)
n10 = n10 - d10
d50 = min(rest100 // 5,  n50)
n50 = n50 - d50
print(n100 + n50 + n10)
```

Comment: Решение прошло столько же тестов, сколько и мое, не прошло те же 2 теста

Comment: Что нужно еще учесть, чтобы решение принялось?

Comment: Что-то, похоже, я не то оптимизировал. Сразу почему-то подумал, что десятки надо приберегать. Добавил обратный вариант, но и там не всё учтено - для 1 9 12 первое решение даёт 9, а второе 10

Comment: 9 решений из 10 верно

Comment: Видимо, в логике есть изъян, но я его не вижу.

Comment: на тесте 9 12 1 выдает 13, а нужно 11

Comment: *а нужно 12. . . .(точки поставил, чтобы до мин длины комментария сделать)